# I messed up my system by installing different python versions, Help! apt-get update gives a CommandNotFound

Tags: apt, 20.04, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I seem to have done some damage to my WSL2 environment by playing around with python versions. Is there any way to fix this? I'm trying to perform an `apt-get update` but I get the following errors:

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_unixsocket'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Here are some elements that could be helpful to fix the situation :

Python installed versions

```
➜  ~ ls -al /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Oct 13  2020 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3674216 Mar  8 14:02 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5203064 May  3 04:51 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 May  3 04:51 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5203064 May  3 04:51 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 May  3 04:51 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5486384 Jan 27 16:41 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jan 27 16:41 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
```

Distro details

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

EDIT:

Trying to run `sudo apt-get install python3-all` yields a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debian'`

Comment: Given that this is a WSL instance, are you not able to throw it away and start with a fresh Ubuntu container? 

Comment: @matigo, yes but I have customized this one a lot and would rather recover it.

Comment: @karel, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debian'` when trying to `sudo apt-get install python3-all`

Comment: Maybe try manually downloading and reinstalling the relevant packages.  Use dpkg -S to search for package name from filename.

Comment: I ended up rebuilding my environment as @matigo suggested. Sadly, it was too complicated to follow the rabbit down the hole and reinstall each package manually.